# Why pushing data to my global array inside observable doesn't fill the array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, observable

I'm currently working on an Angular project as a new angular developer. The project consists of fetching data from Flickr's API (https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) and rendering it to my view (bandeau.component.html). So, to achieve this step, I use the `get()` method from `HttpClientModule` inside my service (flickr.service.ts). It returns a response that I handle parsing and mapping to a custom object (PhotosFeatures) I've created before, inside an observable. So, my problem is when I want to store the data of the mapped object inside a global array of my service and try to print it through a `console.log()` in the TypeScript's file of my component (bandeau.component.ts), it displays an empty array.

My opinion is that the `get()` method runs an asynchronous request. So before it's completed, I fetch data that aren't yet as it is processing by the get method. So it fills my array with empty objects. However, I'm remaining without solutions to troubleshoot this problem.

Could you help me to solve this problem, please?

Here is my code :

bandeau.component.html :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="flickrSearchForm">
  <div>
    <input formControlName="searchFor" id="text" name="user-input" placeholder="Titre, description, tags etc..."
           type="text">
  </div>

  <p>Rechercher par :</p>
  <div aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group" class="btn-group" role="group">
    <input class="btn-check" formControlName="searchBy" id="all" name="searchBy" type="radio" value="all">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="all">Autre</label>

    <input class="btn-check" formControlName="searchBy" id="tags" name="searchBy" type="radio" value="tags">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="tags">Tags</label>

  </div>

  <p>Taille :</p>
  <div aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group" class="btn-group" role="group">
    <input class="btn-check" formControlName="extra" id="small" name="extra" type="radio" value="url_s">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="small">P</label>

    <input class="btn-check" formControlName="extra" id="medium" name="extra" type="radio" value="url_m">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="medium">M</label>

    <input class="btn-check" formControlName="extra" id="big" name="extra" type="radio" value="url_l">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="big">G</label>

  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="date-min-upload">Uploadée après le :</label>
    <input formControlName="min_upload_date" id="date-min-upload" name="date-min-upload" type="date">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="date-max-upload">Uploadée avant le : </label>
    <input formControlName="max_upload_date" id="date-max-upload" name="date-max-upload" type="date">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="date-min-taken">Prise après le :</label>
    <input formControlName="min_taken_date" id="date-min-taken" name="date-min-taken" type="date">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="date-max-taken">Prise avant le : </label>
    <input formControlName="max_taken_date" id="date-max-taken" name="date-max-taken" type="date">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="safe-search">NSFW :</label>
    <select formControlName="safe_search" id="safe-search" name="safe-search">
      <option value="1">Fiable</option>
      <option value="2">Modéré</option>
      <option value="3">Restreint</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="privacy">Visible pour :</label>
    <select formControlName="privacy_filter" id="privacy" name="privacy">
      <option value="1">Tout le monde</option>
      <option value="2">Uniquement pour les amis</option>
      <option value="3">Uniquement pour la famille</option>
      <option value="4">Uniquement pour la famille</option>
      <option value="5">Privée</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Type de contenu :</p>
    <div>
      <label for="content-types-photos">Video</label>
      <input class="form-check-input" formControlName="content_types" id="content-types-photos" name="content_types" type="checkbox" value="0" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="content-types-screenshot">Capture d'écran</label>
      <input class="form-check-input" formControlName="content_types" id="content-types-screenshot" name="content_types" type="checkbox" value="1" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="content-types-virtual-photo">Photo virtuelle</label>
      <input class="form-check-input" formControlName="content_types" id="content-types-virtual-photo" name="content_types" type="checkbox" value="2" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="content-types-other">Autres</label>
      <input class="form-check-input" formControlName="content_types" id="content-types-other" type="checkbox" name="content_types" value="3" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class=" color-picker">
    <p>Couleur :</p>
    <div class="color-palette">
      <label for="color-codes-red">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-red" style="background-color: #ff2000" type="checkbox"
               value="0" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-brown">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-brown" style="background-color: #a24615" type="checkbox"
               value="1" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-orange">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-orange" style="background-color: #ff7c00"
               type="checkbox" value="2" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-pink">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-pink" style="background-color: #ff9f9c" type="checkbox"
               value="b" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-yellow">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-yellow" style="background-color: #fffa00"
               type="checkbox" value="4" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-yellow-dark">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-yellow-dark" style="background-color: #ffcf00"
               type="checkbox" value="3" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-green-light">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-green-light" style="background-color: #90e200"
               type="checkbox" value="5" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-green-dark">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-green-dark" style="background-color: #00ab00"
               type="checkbox" value="6" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-blue-light">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-blue-light" style="background-color: #00b2d4"
               type="checkbox" value="7" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-blue-dark">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-blue-dark" style="background-color: #0062c6"
               type="checkbox" value="8" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-purple">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-purple" style="background-color: #8c20ba"
               type="checkbox" value="9" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-pink-dark">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-pink-dark" style="background-color: #f52394"
               type="checkbox" value="a" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-white">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-white" style="background-color: #ffffff" type="checkbox"
               value="c">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-grey">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-grey" style="background-color: #7c7c7c" type="checkbox"
               value="d" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
      <label for="color-codes-black">
        <input class="color-picker-item" formArrayName="color_codes" id="color-codes-black" style="background-color: #000000" type="checkbox"
               value="e" (change)="onChecboxChange($event)">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Rechercher</button>

</form>
```

bandeau.component.ts (the addParameters function gets data from user's input, processes it and return the parameters I concatenate the base URL of API HTTP request) :

```
 onSubmit(): void {
    let pf = this.fs.getPhotosFeatures(this.addParameters(this.parameters));
    console.log(pf);
  }
```

flickr.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {PhotosFeatures} from "../../Entities/PhotosFeatures";
import {HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";
import {Photos} from "../../Entities/Photos";
import {delay, map, Observable} from "rxjs";
import {FlickrOutput} from "../../Entities/FlickrOutput";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FlickrService {

  private baseUrl: string = "https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?api_key=" + environment.apiKeys + "&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&per_page=500&method=flickr.photos.search&";
  public pf: PhotosFeatures[] = [];
  private photos?: Photos[];

  constructor(public http : HttpClient) { }


  getPf() : PhotosFeatures[] {
    return this.pf;
  }

  getPhotosFeatures(requestParam: string) : Observable<PhotosFeatures[]> {
    this.pf = [];
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + requestParam)
      .pipe(map((data: any) => {
          delay(10000)
          data.photos.photo.forEach((ph: PhotosFeatures) => {

            }
          )
        return this.pf;
        }
      ))

  }

}
```

PhotosFeatures.ts :

```
export interface PhotosFeatures {
  id: string;
  server: string;
  secret: string,
  title: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `this.pf` never gets pushed any data, so it will always remain empty.

Now, the other thing to understand is that getPhotosFeatures is returning an observable (which is a good thing, since as you said, you are doing asynchronous actions) but you are logging it just as if it was a value.

An observable to not do anything until it is subscribed to, so first thing to do is subscribing to it:

```
let pf = this.fs.getPhotosFeatures(this.addParameters(this.parameters)).subscribe(pf=>console.log(pf));
```

With this, I have subscribed to the observable, and the function passed will be called with the data when it arrives, in this case I simply console.log it.

Now, another problem is your map inside your service, you are returning this.pf which will always be an empty array since you don't do anything to it. ALso your delay has no effect where you put it, you'll need to put it inside your map either before or after the map.

```
.pipe(delay(10000),map((data: any) => {
      const pf = [];
      data.photos.photo.forEach((ph: PhotosFeatures) => {
            // Do stuff?
            pf.push(ph);
        }
      )
    return pf;
    }
  ));
```

See, I changed PF to be local instead of a property of the service, there is no reason to cause side effects I think. And I finally return pf as you did, but now it should be filled since we do pf.push on it.

I hope it clears things a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Salketer, it helps me a lot. I changed my service code. However, when I want to access one element of the array, it prints `undefined` in the console. Here is my updated `onSubtmit()` function : 

`onSubmit(): void {
    let tab: any[] = []
    this.fs.getPhotosFeatures(this.addParameters(this.parameters))
      .subscribe(pf => pf.forEach(pf => tab.push(pf)));
    console.log(tab[0]);
  }`

Comment: Would you please check the value of pf, does it hold values?

Comment: yes it is : 

`Array []
​
0: Object { id: "52552937335", owner: "33886175@N08", secret: "48d50be819", … }
​
1: Object { id: "52552008447", owner: "184079082@N05", secret: "cb1595bde5", … }
​
2: Object { id: "52552469846", owner: "194545053@N03", secret: "b68a1d1b0b", … }
​
3: Object { id: "52552455576", owner: "10537200@N00", secret: "77cfc063c2", … }
​
4: Object { id: "52551990742", owner: "10537200@N00", secret: "d57932ba3f", … }`

Comment: Ah wait I ddidn't see your code correctly, you need to log inside the subscribe, because when you log the tab did not receive the data yet. Basic asynchronous mistake

Comment: Ty for your help, my friend. All the best!